# Connect Excel on SharePoint as Tableau datasource

Tags: excel, sharepoint, tableau-api

I have an Excel file on my organization's SharePoint. I need to make the excel file as the data source in the tableau and it has to be real-time updated. How do I connect those two?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to connect Excel files through SharePoint directly.
There are two workaround about this:

1. What am I doing usually if I want to connect Tableau to my Excel in SharePoint is by syncing my SharePoint across my local computers.This way, I only need to re-connect the data from the synced SharePoint folder on my computer every time I change computer.
2. Import your Excel into SharePoint List and connect Tableau to the Sharepoint List. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa) is how to import Excel to SharePoint List

Answer (score 0):

You have an option on SharePoint Library section open with explorer
[Refer to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5xb4.png)

1. Open with explorer
2. Copy the file path from address section of explorer
3. In Tableau while connecting the excel use the path to connect to the excel file that is on the share drive.

This will help give live connection from the excel file in SharePoint.